# Circuit for 2 Switches and 2 LED's

Tags: button

I have a circuit with 2 switches and 2 LED's. I want to control one LED with 1 button (which is a simple circuit). But I also want to turn off one of them, when the other is On. Is there a simple way to do this?

Overall, I should be able to turn both of them off, and only one should be on at a time.

Both switches are latching push on/push off switches.

Comment: Do you have switches or buttons?

Comment: Its just a push button, which is a switch.

Comment: Use a SR latch.

Comment: What kind of switches do you have? SPST? DPDT?

Comment: What is the usage of this circuit? Is there any priority for LEDs?

Comment: I am sorry to have not mentioned that. It is a momentary push button( ie, once pressed and left it is connected. And pressed again & left, it becomes disconnected)

Comment: @Sherby That's not a momentary push button. A momentary stays on only as long as you press it. You're describing an ON-OFF button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One SPDT (Or a DPDT just use one side) and a push button. If both leds are the same, you could use just one resistor, since neither is on at the same time. The button, since it is latching, still doesn't affect how the SPDT switch works. Only one will be on at any given time, or both off.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fn01xO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Another version would have the latching button work as a master on/off switch, with the SPDT selects between the two leds.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqkf9a.png)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! I am sorry to have not mentioned that. It is a momentary push button( ie, once pressed and left it is connected. And pressed again & left, it becomes disconnected)

Comment: @Sherby a momentary button has to be held. You have a latching button. Also called a Push On/Push Off button. In a schematic, they work the same. You could move that button between the battery and the SPDT and it would work as a master on off switch instead.

Comment: @Sherby updated

Comment: Thanks, This is almost what I want, but since I have both the momentary switches, I might have to make some changes(on the SPDT).

Answer (score 1):

With only push-buttons, LEDs, and resistors I think the best you can get away with is to allow only one to be on at a time. Without logic you have no way of arbitrating which one stays on if you push both button at the same time.

I think this would work for that.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwiJDt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I dont see how this would work .Pressing switch 1, would pass the current through LED and the direct wire to R2. More would pass through R2 as less resistance. But pressing S2 will not turn LED 1 off.

Comment: Yes current would also go through R2 while LED1 is on, it doesn't matter except for a waste of power. If both switches are pushed then both terminals of both LEDs would be at the same potential, thus would not be able to be on. This is an XOR operation.

Comment: Nice. But If I turn S1 ON at first, then turning S2 ON would end with both being OFF,wouldnt it?

Comment: Yes, which is what is written in the text above the schematic.

Comment: @Passerby Ha, thanks for that. Though without the rotation, it doesn't have the same meaning.

Comment: @Samuel yea, it looks different, but its still electronically the same. It's just that that image jumped out at me and I had to remove it. Like I said, it was probably unintentional :D

Comment: @Passerby Entirely unintentional. It's better now.